# Python CSV lookup

Tags: python-2.7, csv

Taking in to consideration two csv files;

- A.csv containing 180 rows
- B.csv containing 1400 rows.

Why the bellow code will only print the B.csv rows at the first iteration of A.csv?

```
with open('A.csv', 'rU') as a_data, open('B.csv', 'rU') as b_data:
        a_rows = csv.reader(a_data, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        b_rows = csv.reader(b_data, delimiter='\t')

        for a_row in a_rows:
            print a_row[0]

            for b_row in b_rows:
                print b_row[0]
```

Supposing that:

- The index 0 of the A.csv rows is a sequence of integers starting at 1000.
- The index 0 of the B.csv rows is a sequence of integers starting at 10000.

Here is the representation of what is printed:

```
1000
10001
10002
.
.
.
11398
11399
1001
1002
1003
.
.
.
1179
```

Comment: Why would the CSV reader rewind again? It is not a list object.

Comment: You can rewind by seeking `b_data` to the start again; `b_data.seek(0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b_rows is the csv reader pointer and not a list. So this reads line by line until EOD of b_rows in the first iteration.

In the next successive a_row iterations, b_rows will be always pointed to empty.